# fire .net event from jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, events

I have an image on my page than can be changed from a fileupload asp.net control on the page, i want to provide and alternative to clicking the button by allowing the user to click their image. i gave the fileupload a class 'jqueryPhotoUploadTrigger' and it renders like this:

```
<input type="file" name="ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$C2kMasterPlaceholder$ucEditDetails_20$photoupload" id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderDefault_C2kMasterPlaceholder_ucEditDetails_20_photoupload" class="jqueryPhotoUploadTrigger" />
```

i then have jquery script at the bottom:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#clickMyColl").click(function () {

            alert("image has been clicked");
            $('.jqueryPhotoUploadTrigger').click();
        });
 });
```

the alert does show so i know the script is firing when i click the image. i was just hoping the .click would fire the event on the button but it didnt. can i do it this way or must i find an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

you could do a submit or use the Ajax way, there are functions like __doPostback(), look in the ASP.NET documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You could either to an ajax call of have an ImageButton on the page with a transparent image (so its hidden)

then in your jquery you could use

```
 $("#yourhiddenbutton").click();
```

this would then fire the server side click event

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've to set the **focus** on the input (if I've understood your question):

```
$('.jqueryPhotoUploadTrigger').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the ID of your image as "#clickMyColl", but instead use the ID as it is rendered (jQuery does not know the asp ID): "ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderDefault_C2kMasterPlaceholder_ucEditDetails_20_photoupload"

Alternatively, you could use the class to select:
$(".jqueryPhotoUploadTrigger").click(function ...